# How to Determine Azure App Service Plan SKUs Available in a Specific Subscription/Location Before Creation?

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-app-service-plans, server-farm

- In the Microsoft documentation, there is a well-documented API endpoint to list the available App Service Plan SKUs/Capabilities for an existing App Service Plan. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/app-service-plans/list-capabilities)
- However, when attempting to create a new Service Plan for a specific subscription/location, there seems to be no direct endpoint or method provided to retrieve a list of available SKUs beforehand.
- Is there a way to programmatically determine the App Service Plan SKUs supported in a provided Azure subscription and location before creating the App Service Plan or the `Microsoft.Web/serverfarms` resource?

Comment: Are you trying to code in ARM template or any other coding method? @dulithm

Comment: Does Azure PowerShell or CLI also works for your requirement? @dulithm

Comment: @Jahnavi Yes I'm trying to create an ARM template.
I'm developing an internal web app to provision App services
and need to show available SKUs in a dropdown for a given location.
Unfortunately, Azure CLI might not be a good option for me

Comment: Azure bicep works for you? @dulithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to Determine Azure App Service Plan SKUs Available in a Specific Subscription/Location Before Creation?

*Programmatically, it is not possible to retrieve it using ARM template however, you can achieve the requirement using PowerShell or Azure resource graph query explorer which are detailed below.*

***AZ PowerShell:***

```
$appservice =  Get-AzAppServicePlan -Location "West US"
foreach($app in $appservice){
 $resourceGroup = $app.ResourceGroup
 $appName = $app.Name    
 $resources = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup | Where-Object { $_.ResourceName -eq $appName }
 $sku = $resources.Sku
 $skus += $sku    
}
```

[image]

**Or**

```
(Get-AzAppServicePlan -Location "West US").SKU
```

[image]

***Azure Resource Graph Query:***

```
resources
| where type =~ "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"  and location has  "WestUS"
| project sku
```

[image]

```
resources
| where type =~ "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms"  and subscriptionId has  "xxxxx"
| project sku.tier
```

[image]

Comment: As per my understanding, this `Get-AzAppServicePlan` would need to have already created app service plans for a given location.
Later I found this API endpoint, that would work: [list-biling-meters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/list-billing-meters/list-billing-meters)

Comment: Did you try running the query which I've given above. @dulithm

Comment: Is it working now or still the issue persists? @dulithm

Comment: Thanks! It works! 
but what I needed was an API endpoint,
so I'm using this: [list-billing-meters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/list-billing-meters/list-billing-meters)